# KeyError: Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0 on trainer.fit(model, data_module) line

Tags: python

I am training a VISUAL BERT model on MAMI dataset and I am getting following error when trying to run the code:

```
KeyError: Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3807, in 
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3804, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

Error on the line : `trainer.fit(model, data_module)`

Comment: Please provide the relevant code and some ideas on the cause of the bug